Cant select bone in weight painting mode
Following the tutorial from youtube, after creating the skeleton, you need to switch to the weight painting mode.
It seems to me that I do everything exactly the same as the author, however, I can't select a bone using ctrl+left click.
Please tell me what could be the problem?



In newer versions it has been changed to Alt + left click.

@joshsanfelici ohhhh why I even didnt try this combination? thanks!

For the moment your body is not parented to the armature, there's no Armature modifier in the modifiers panel, you need to parent it With Automatic Weights, then select the armature, shift select the body, switch to Weight Paint mode, and select the bone with CtrlLMB (or ShiftLMB if you want to select several bones)

Using Blender 4.2, and it turns out for me, on the Cinnamon (Linux) desktop specifically,  the problem was that Cinnamon was stealing the Alt + Click functionality.
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=264172
